# When was hydroponics utilized for the first time in a sci-fi movie or a sci-fi TV show?

Tags: movie, history-of, science-fiction-genre

In the realms of sci-fi (movie or TV) with extra-terrestrial environments, from the perspective of life support, technological systems are present in order to allow human beings to survive and function. Hydroponics, as a plant nursery, is one of them.

Hydroponics, a soil-less plant-growth method for a sterile environment, enables plants to grow healthy (disease-free) without the use of pesticides and less water.

I remember from the TV series *Lost in Space* in the 60s about the use of a hydroponic garden. But, when was hydroponics used successfully, or not, in a sci-fi movie or a TV show.

I found that in *The Time Travelers* (1964) there is a scene with a hydroponics but I think that exist other prior sci-fi movies or sci-fi TV shows featuring this concept.

[image]

Comment: Seems like, at least, since the 50s, but probably another 30 years older.  I mean its kind of a variant on the greenhouse which has been around for a long time.

Comment: Real world hydroponics started in the 1620s, so this could go back to the early history of SF movies.

Comment: I'm going to guess mayyyyybe 1956's  _[Forbidden Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet)_ has hydroponics because of all the sophisticated underground stuff, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Spencer, nothing like that is shown. The earliest big example I can think of is 1972’s [Silent Running](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Running)

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Yeah, I was thinking _Silent Running_ at first, but OP mentioned _Lost in Space_ which was well before that.